# Fibers in Python

Tags: python, generator, fibers

I'm looking for a very simple way to implement [fibers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fiber_(computer_science)) in Python. I'm sure there's a really simple way to do it using generators, but my mind is crapping out on me. This isn't for a huge application, so I don't need the fanciness (or the overhead) of something like Diesel or Tornado or Twisted, I just want a neat little way to do fibers. Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577129-run-asynchronous-tasks-using-coroutines/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've discovered that [Greenlets](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/greenlet) do pretty much exactly what I've been looking to do. Sweet!

Answer (score 0):

Google around for Python coroutines.  There's a lot of stuff out there with varying levels of complexity.